# Comparison Between Two Queries Using Execution Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2019

I am trying to compare two queries using this link from Stack Overflow [Query Performances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875368/subquery-total-performance-vs-case-sum-performance). It's an old post that I checked and when tried to analyse the query performances using execution plan, bit confused. So here that I did to find out the differences:

Created the table with no index:

```
create table tbl 
(
    id int identity primary key, 
    a int,
    b int,
    c int, 
    d int
)

insert tbl values (1, 2, 3, null)
insert tbl values (2, null, 3, 1)
insert tbl values (1, null, 1, 4)
insert tbl values (1, null, 3, 5)
insert tbl values (1, null, 3, 6)

insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --10
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --20
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --40
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --80
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --160
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --320
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --640
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --1280
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --2560
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --5120
insert tbl select a, b, c, d from tbl --10240
```

I then executed these queries:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(a) FROM tbl WHERE a = 1) AS a,
    (SELECT SUM(b) FROM tbl WHERE b = 2) AS b,
    (SELECT SUM(c) FROM tbl WHERE c = 3) AS c

SELECT
    SUM((CASE WHEN a = 1 THEN a ELSE NULL END)),
    SUM((CASE WHEN b = 2 THEN b ELSE NULL END)),
    SUM((CASE WHEN c = 3 THEN c  ELSE NULL END))
FROM
    tbl
```

According to the previous post and accepted as answer (the link that I've given above); I won't bore you with images here but look at the plan which will show a cost of about 75% against the top query and 25% against the bottom. That's expected, 75%:25% = 3:1 which is due to the first query passing through the table 3 times exactly.

In my case, when I run queries, I get the opposite results as follows:

For the first query with subquery:

[image: Three Subqueries]

For the second query with `case`:

[image: Query With Case]

According to my understanding the second query would be faster and cost would be less as compared to the one I get (Got 85% and the original poster mentioned that should be around 25%) as it runs in a single query. For query one, as it has three queries, have cost of 27%. I believe, combinedly that would become 81% that seems less than the second query in my execution plan.

My question would be - Is there anything that I missed or misinterpreted with the execution plan or it's the expected cost that I supposed to get?

Comment: The "costs" are relative to the query, and are estimates. That  the 3 scans were 27% each doesn't make them "better" than the one scan of that table as those numbers aren't comparable; the value is out of 100%, so of course if you have *more things* happening, the cost of each part respectively is going to be lower overall. That doesn't mean that the cost of the operation was lower.

Comment: Put it this way, let's say you buy a single bottle of water and a packet of crisps; the water was 60% of the total. If you then buy *three* bottles of water, and a package of crips, the percentage cost of each bottle of water is now 27%, but the actual *cost* of each bottle is the same.

Comment: What you should *really* be doing it looking at things like the total rows read, and timings. As you have *three* scans, this means that the table `tbl` was read 3 times, and every row in that table was read each time. So, very quickly, we can see that the first query read *three times* the amount of data that the second query did. *If* you had `INDEX`es on `tbl` for each column, you would likely see seeks, not scans, which could easily result in a (very) different story. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZlnYO55z)

Comment: So the overall cost that I get, say for second query wouldn't be less (In my case 85%) or I should consider to calculate it in any other way? I am assuming the cost here is the time, CPU usage etc.

Comment: Forget the query cost (or query bucks as Erik Darling calls them) they are mostly meaningless. Use `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;` and compare the reads and CPU time. I guarantee you the second query is actually faster. Anyway, you are not adding it up correctly, because there is also the cost of the extra `Stream Aggregate` nodes, so that makes a total of 99%, ergo the whole calculation is only relative to that query not to other queries.

Comment: In future please share the link using https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan, not using images which are mostly useless.

Comment: I am sharing an image here - https://ibb.co/pvBY8Lm and am trying to figure out performance of a query (That uses no. of subqueries) using this statement SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;. In local, the query run fast around 5000 rows but in production, it takes around 1 to 00:01:20. Here's the image link - https://ibb.co/VCS2L53. Now the one using SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON; statement, how I can get the total elapsed time of the query (Total execution time) or I should calculate all of the elapsed time shown in the image? @Charlieface.

Comment: Could you please look into my previous comment? @ThomA.

Comment: *"Could you please look into my previous comment?"* @Charlieface responded to you on that though. On those images, if they are important use the [edit] feature. I have no idea what those links are, and I won't clicking them.

Comment: I thought I just said to upload the plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. If you don't want to give us the necessary information we can't help. Either way, this is essentially a different question from what you asked originally, now you want to know why it's slow on the prod server. There is also quite clearly completely different tables involved. I suggest you delete this question and just create a new one with all the necessary info (full query, tables and index definitions, query plan)

Comment: Please check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78232184/query-plan-estimation-and-performance-improvement-of-a-query @ThomA. Would be deleting this one.

Comment: Please check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78232184/query-plan-estimation-and-performance-improvement-of-a-query @Charlieface. Would be deleting this one.