# Query Plan Estimation and Performance Improvement of A Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2019

I am trying to analyse execution time of a query. I used the following statement to check CPU and elapsed time:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
```

For a single query, I can understand the CPU and elapsed time. But when it comes to a complex query, say as follows (Pretty big and for the time being, not sharing any sample data):

```
DECLARE @userID BIGINT = 100, @type bit =0
DECLARE @fetchDate DATETIME;

SET @fetchDate = DATEADD(yy,-2,datediff(d,0,getdate()))

DECLARE @subuserId BIGINT;
SELECT @subuserId = dbo.fn_getSubstituteForUser(@userID)

DECLARE @userGradeLevelCode NVARCHAR(20);

SELECT @userGradeLevelCode = GradeLevelCode
FROM Tbl_UserPost pst
LEFT JOIN Tbl_MasterGradeLevel gd ON pst.GradeLevel_ID = gd.GradeLevel_ID
WHERE pst.IsActive = 1 AND pst.User_ID = @userID

SELECT 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MemoForAllID ORDER BY MemoForAllDetailID DESC) r,
    SenderID, MemoForAllID, 
    ReceiverIndividualIDs, MemoForAllDetailID,
    Status, IsUpdated, IsTransfered, CreatedBy
INTO 
    #temp_VW_Tbl_MemoForAllDetail 
FROM 
    VW_Tbl_MemoForAllDetail 
WHERE
    IsActive = 1 AND CreatedOn > @fetchDate

SELECT
    header.MemoForAllID,
    detail.MemoForAllDetailID,
    header.Subject,
    header.Code,
    header.DocumentNumber,
    detail.SenderID,
    CASE 
        WHEN (dd.GradeLevelCode = 'DEL')  
            THEN dd.DepartmentName 
        WHEN @type = 0 OR detail.Status IN ('REVIEW', 'DRAFT', 'CORRECTION') 
            THEN dd.EmployeeName 
        ELSE
            CASE 
                WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT dlg1.DelegateID 
                                  FROM Tbl_MemoForAllDelegateDetail dlg1 
                                  WHERE dlg1.MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID 
                                    AND dlg1.IsActive = 1) 
                      AND detail.Status NOT IN ('REVIEW', 'CORRECTION'))
                    THEN 
                        (SELECT DirectorateName 
                         FROM tbl_MasterDirectorate msd 
                         INNER JOIN tbl_UserPost pst ON pst.Directorate_ID = msd.Directorate_ID 
                         WHERE pst.IsActive = 1 
                           AND pst.User_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 dlg1.SenderID 
                                              FROM Tbl_MemoForAllDelegateDetail dlg1 
                                              WHERE dlg1.MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID 
                                                AND dlg1.DelegateID = @userID 
                                                AND dlg1.IsActive = 1))
                ELSE 
                    (SELECT  DirectorateName 
                     FROM tbl_MasterDirectorate msd 
                     INNER JOIN tbl_UserPost pst ON pst.Directorate_ID = msd.Directorate_ID 
                     WHERE pst.IsActive = 1 
                       AND pst.User_ID = header.SenderID)
            END
    END AS SenderName,
    header.MemoForAllDate,
    header.Priority AS PriorityName,
    detail.Status,
    CASE 
        WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT dlg1.DelegateID 
                          FROM Tbl_MemoForAllDelegateDetail dlg1 
                          WHERE dlg1.MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID 
                            AND dlg1.IsActive = 1) 
                         AND detail.Status NOT IN ('REVIEW', 'CORRECTION'))
            THEN (SELECT TOP 1 dlg1.CreatedOn 
                  FROM Tbl_MemoForAllDelegateDetail dlg1 
                  WHERE dlg1.MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID 
                    AND dlg1.DelegateID = @userID 
                    AND dlg1.IsActive = 1)
        ELSE header.MemoForAllDate
    END AS SentOn,      
    CASE 
        WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(header.CCIDs, ',')))  
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(header.CCSubIDs, ',')))
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(dlgt.CCDelegateIDs, ',')))
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END AS IsCCUser,  
    CASE
        WHEN (@subuserId <> 0)
            THEN CAST(0 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT)
    END AS CanTakeAction,
    detail.IsUpdated,
    CASE 
        WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT a.SenderID 
                          FROM Tbl_MemoForAllDelegateDetail a 
                          WHERE a.MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID 
                            AND a.IsActive = 1))
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END AS HasAssignedDelegate,
    CASE 
        WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT value 
                          FROM STRING_SPLIT(header.RecipientIDs, ',')) 
              AND detail.Status NOT IN ('REVIEW', 'CORRECTION'))
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(header.RecipientSubIDs, ',')) 
              AND detail.Status NOT IN ('REVIEW', 'CORRECTION'))
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT dlg.DelegateID FROM Tbl_MemoForAllDelegateDetail dlg WHERE dlg.MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID AND dlg.IsActive = 1 ) AND detail.Status NOT IN ('REVIEW', 'CORRECTION'))
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END AS CanFreeze,
    CASE WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT a.User_ID FROM Tbl_MemoForAllFreezeDetail a WHERE a.MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID AND a.IsActive = 1 ))
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)

        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END AS HasFreezed,
    CASE WHEN (
                header.MemoForAllID IN (SELECT DISTINCT a.MemoForAllRefID FROM Tbl_MemoForAllHeader a WHERE a.CreatedBy = @userID and CreatedOn > @fetchDate) 
                AND @userID IN (SELECT a.User_ID FROM Tbl_MemoForAllFreezeDetail a WHERE a.MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID AND a.IsActive = 1  )
            )
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END AS IsReffered,
    'MemoForAll' MemoType,
    CAST(0 AS BIT) IsMemoClosed,
    CAST(0 AS BIT) IsFinalSent,
    CASE WHEN (@userID IN (SELECT dlg.DelegateID FROM Tbl_MemoForAllDelegateDetail dlg WHERE dlg.MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID AND dlg.IsActive = 1  ) AND detail.Status NOT IN ('REVIEW', 'CORRECTION'))
            THEN CAST(1 AS bigint)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS bigint)
    END AS RecipientDelegate_ID,
    CAST(0 AS BIT) IsForwarded,
    CASE WHEN (header.Status NOT IN ('DRAFT','REVIEW') AND  @userGradeLevelCode IN ('DIR'))
            THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END AS CanTransfer,
    detail.IsTransfered,
    detail.CreatedBy
FROM Tbl_MemoForAllHeader header

 LEFT JOIN Tbl_MemoForAllDelegateDetail dlgt ON header.MemoForAllID = dlgt.MemoForAllID AND dlgt.ID = (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Tbl_MemoForAllDelegateDetail
    WHERE MemoForAllID = header.MemoForAllID AND IsActive = 1
     
)
INNER JOIN 
    #temp_VW_Tbl_MemoForAllDetail detail
    ON (header.MemoForAllID = detail.MemoForAllID)

inner join VW_UserInfo dd on dd.User_ID=detail.SenderID

WHERE 
detail.r =1 and header.CreatedOn > @fetchDate
and header.IsActive = 1 AND header.IsForAllDirectors = 0
AND (
        (header.IsForAllDirectors = 0 AND header.Status IN ('ADD_DELEGATE') AND @userID IN(SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(header.RecipientIDs,',')) )
        OR @userID IN(SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(header.CCSecretaryIDs,','))
        OR (header.Status IN ('REVIEW') AND (header.OriginatorID = @userID OR header.OriginatorSubID = @userID))
    )
AND header.Status NOT IN ('DRAFT')

DROP TABLE #temp_VW_Tbl_MemoForAllDetail
```

The performance degrades in production, in my understanding it could be due to no. of `CAST()` and subqueries (As I didn't write the actual query) with `CASE` statement. If any suggestion provided on assumption, would be glad to know more about optimizing.

Now my actual query is something different that I am unable to figure out. When I run the query on production, I get the following:

**Image 1**:
[image: Query Execution 1]

For 4970 rows, it takes around **00:01:20**. In local, it's pretty fast. When I use this statement `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;`, got the below:

**Image 2**:
[image: Query Execution 2]

My question is, the execution time I get in the first image would be the same with the second image. I am willing to know like how the calculation done in the second image for execution time of the query. I can see no. of elapsed time for each scan, to sum up and to get the actual execution time should I calculate all the elapsed time in the second image?

Any brief explanation would be great.

**N.B**: I am pretty novice in analysing `SQL` queries, please pardon if I missed anything or suggest anything that can improve the post.

Comment: Posting images of text is *not* helpful.

Comment: Anything that could be useful for this post or I can improve? @Thom A. I am interested to know more about the terms used in the second image and how that could help me to analyse.

Comment: I think the CASTs are the least of the issues here. You have a lot of STRING_SPLIT; correlated subqueries with INs, ORs, TOP 1 subqueries, to be honest, i'm not sure if this query is serious, a joke, EF core translation or some sort of stress test for SQL parser. You should probably look into splitting it a bit. As for SET TIME ON, it won't exactly match the running time. I suggest starting with query plan analysis though

Comment: *"Anything that could be useful for this post or I can improve?"* Don't post images of text.